# Range.PasteSpecial causes an Application ScreenUpdate in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA Macro for Excel that looks like the following:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim copyingRange, pastingRange As Range
copyingRange.Cells.Copy
pastingRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

It is my understanding that `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` will force the application to stop screen updates however this is not the behavior I am seeing.  I am copying a range from one sheet to another and the application switches views to and from very quickly, an undesirable effect.

Taking out the line `pastingRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` causes the screen flickering to go away but obviously results in the macro not doing what I want.

Is the `pastingRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` the problem here? I must be misunderstanding something here?

Comment: You can avoid copy/paste since you just want values and write:  `pastingrange.value = copyingrange.value`

Comment: Specific to your question, hwat else is going on in your code?  are you using any `.activate` language for antoehr workbook or sheet?  Just to be safe, you're not running the macro from VBA (particularly not stepping through) as this would negate the screenupdating = false.  HOpefully last question:  what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Jimmy, note that if you use any .activate or .select language, the screenupdating is set back to true

Comment: Cyril - That is very useful to know! Would you happen to know why the `pasteSpecial` method sets screenupdating back to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment, so this can be listed as **Answered**:

You can avoid copy/paste since you just want values and write:

```
pastingrange.value = copyingrange.value
```